# React Native "global" variable Intellij undefined

Tags: typescript, react-native

This is app.tsx

```
{global.HermesInternal == null ? null : (
    <View style={styles.engine}>
    <Text style={styles.footer}>Engine: Hermes</Text>
    </View>
)}
```

This is package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.15",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.2",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.60.15",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.8.2",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.13",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3"
  },
```

I get a type error message from **Intellij only** *"Unresolved variable of type global"*, but **the app runs successfully**. I tried adding `@types/node` and then a type error about `HermesInternal` not being part of global object is thrown.

---

Just for refernce in `@types/react-native/index.d.ts` this is the declaration:

```
declare global {
    ...
    const HermesInternal: null | {};
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I suspect this is a problem with the react native typings. As you've seen, the typings export a global `HermesInternal` object, but they don't declare the `global` parent object itself.

As a workaround, you can include this declaration above your component:

```
declare global {
  const global: { HermesInternal: null | {} }
}
```

Not ideal, but hopefully we will see an updated typings file to fix this issue. I'm currently on `@types/react-native@0.60.15`.